# In some cases it's weird to close a question as a duplicate of a bad closed question

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing a reopen on:
[What is the best way to implement "remember me" for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website)

And it struck me as if that should just be deleted. I cannot be due to all the links to it and that it's the parent of closed duplicates.

That said, the question should really: point out what framework and or language the implementation intended to be in, and then note what was tried and concerns about it what specifically needs to be improved.

The issue seems to be that not only is it a poor question, if one asked a better specific version of this question, its possible it could get closed as a duplicate of this closed question. But how is that useful?

I see that some duplicates should be closed as being closed for the same reason the parent was closed (essentially). But that's not because it's a duplicate, so much as it's a similarly bad question for the same reasons the parent is bad.

When something is closed as a duplicate the implication is that the parent is the right place to read the same question and find or write the same answers the closed question would have had. This does not make sense in the context of a closed parent.

Maybe it shouldn't be possible to mark a question a duplicate of a closed question.

I hope this isn't a duplicate...

Comment: If this is a duplicate, I hope it's a duplicate of a closed question.

Comment: @resueman On this site that's likely and potentially useful in a different way than the scenario I am looking at. Any opinion on the utility of old, general poorly formed questions?

Comment: Well, how would that better question go? You are welcome to edit it into shape.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not going to "show my work" and specify the actual language and tools for a question that I don't actually have. No one else will either. So they make a new question, it might get an answer or get marked as a duplicate of this. IF it's a duplicate of this they would then... edit it to be their question... but the answer doesn't apply specifically to them so, they can't choose a better answer can they?

Comment: I'd definitely lean more toward closing for a reason other than duplicate instead of closing as a dupe of a closed question.

Comment: What if the closed duplicate has a useful answer? Wouldn't marking it as a dupe of that closed question at least be useful?

Comment: @KevinB yeah sometimes. But say you couldn't mark as a dupe of closed questions... then someone could just comment on the question, which might be getting closed, with: Look at this old answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/244907/459

Comment: I think that bad questions should be closed for the reason that they are bad, if they are would make good signposts then they should be closed as a duplicate. I see no reason in holding on to crap questions just because they are similar to other crap questions.